# React state array is being updated by a different value other than the setState

Tags: reactjs, arrays, state

```
const selectToppingSide = (ww, j) => {
    var extraName = ww.ExtraName;
    var extraCodeI = ww.ExtraCode;
    var extraDescription = j.extraDescription;
    var extraCode = j.extraCode;

    var a = ww;

    if (j.extraDescription === "FirstHalf") {
      a.PizzaFirstHalf = 1;
      a.PizzaSecondHalf = null;
      a.ExtraPrice = j.extraPrice;
      a.CartExtra_MenuItemExtraID = j.menuItemExtraID;
    }
    if (j.extraDescription === "Full") {
      a.PizzaFirstHalf = null;
      a.PizzaSecondHalf = null;
      a.ExtraPrice = j.extraPrice;
      a.CartExtra_MenuItemExtraID = j.menuItemExtraID;
    }
    if (j.extraDescription === "SecondHalf") {
      a.PizzaFirstHalf = null;
      a.PizzaSecondHalf = 1;
      a.ExtraPrice = j.extraPrice;
      a.CartExtra_MenuItemExtraID = j.menuItemExtraID;
    }

    if (selectedToppings.length < 1) {
      setSelectedToppings(selectedToppings.concat(ww));
     // setSelectedToppings([...selectedToppings, ww]);
    } 
}
```

When I hit this function it takes in data (ww, j). I set a = ww and set the values of a based on j's data. When i am debugging this and am changing a.PizzaFirstHalf, a.PizzaSecondHalf, a.ExtraPrice, a.CartExtra_MenuItemExtraID in the if statements it is updating my setSelectedToppings state array with those lines of code when it should not be updating them. Later on down this function (not shown in the code i have posted) I am trying to check the selectedToppings array values but I am not checking the values I want to check because the if statements above are changing the values in my setSelectedToppings state array.

Comment: How are you setting your initial states and what kind of data you are sending to ww and j?

Comment: How i am setting states: const [selectedToppings, setSelectedToppings] = useState([]);

Comment: I am sending data about pizza items to ww and j

Comment: @first let me know when you see this

Comment: @first The ww and j are coming in from my database and being displayed though a map function on the frontend. I am then clicking buttons on the frontend with this data connected to it which is then being sent to the function i have posted